# Can't install Lumia Denim with Developer Preview

Tags: lumia-denim-update

I have a Nokia Lumia 630 Dual-Sim with Developer Preview, i have no more updates and i still have Lumia cyan. Am i wrong to assume that i can test denim with this phone?
"Will it run on my...
Yes! Lumia 520, Lumia 525, Lumia 620, Lumia 1520, HTC 8X, Samsung ATIV whatever...you can 'Preview' 8.1 on all of these phones and get all the same features, even Cortana. Cortana is only available in the US? Change your region or just use the default Bing search like now."
http://www.windowscentral.com/how-sign-windows-phone-81-preview-developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, it says you have Cyan while you actually have Denim. To make sure, switch off developer preview, restart the phone and check again, you will see it is Denim now, turn the DP on again, it will be back to Cyan.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought it was a bug that some phones said they have Denim installed but actually still were on cyan

Comment: Do you have a source or reference for this 'known bug' ?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that for now the Dev Preview will only update your phone to the latest version of Windows Phone OS, not the Nokia-specific Updates like Cyan or Denim. You'll get those as soon as they are officially released for your phone. (I hear this will change in the near future, though. Then the firmware updates for Lumia phones should be included.)