# Lumia 525 shows both Lumia Denim and Lumia Cyan?

Tags: settings, lumia-denim-update, lumia-cyan-update

Im using DP in my Lumia 525, while DP is enabled Extras+Info shows Lumia Cyan whereas by disabling it shows Lumia Denim in Extras+Info under Settings. Why it shows Lumia Cyan as i have Lumia Denim.

Where Firmware version is same during those changes in DP.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/7423/106

Comment: How it relates to that post @RowlandShaw

Comment: The accepted answer on that "This is a known bug, it says you have Cyan while you actually have Denim. To make sure, switch off developer preview, restart the phone and check again, you will see it is Denim now, turn the DP on again, it will be back to Cyan."